# How to query in couchdb with multiple key combinations using javascript without writing separate view for each combination?

Tags: javascript, view, couchdb

I am trying to fetch documents from couchdb based on certain specific filters through javascript. For example i need to get the list of employees from a db where the key can be either city, age, state, gross income, gender or a combination of two or more such keys.

The problem i am facing is as the number of possible keys increase the number of views i need to write also increases drastically. I want to avoid writing so many views. So is it possible to do so ??

Comment: couchdb-lucene would probably be your best option.  If you use cloudant it is built in.

Comment: i tried using lucene with my current couchdb installation. I was able to setup lucene correctly but i am not able to get any filtered results out of it as for every query i am getting a response from couchdb as {"code":500}. here is the setup instructions and the example code that i followed : http://foaa.de/old-blog/2011/05/squeeze-couchdb-lucene/trackback/index.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to checking out Matt's suggestion about couchdb-lucene, you might also look into list functions: they're quite useful when you have a small set of basic view queries that will reduce the number of records fetched to a manageable level and you want to do a bunch of ad-hoc queries that further filter those records.